# SSL Integration issue

Tags: https, godaddy

We have a godaddy VPS account and purchased an ssl certificate.We downloaded a .zip file that contains a .cert file.

When we are trying to setup ssl, they are asking .key file with the .cert file, we dont have .key file .

anybody know from where we got the .key file?

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
VKS

Answer (score 1):

During SSL ordering process you were asked to provide Certificate Signing Request (CSR). When CSR is generated, a matching private key file is created. This is the `.key` file you need (along with your SSL certificate) to complete SSL configuration on your web server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,If i miss the key , any way to regenerate this?

Comment: The CSR that was sent to your SSL provider contains the public key which corresponds to the missing private key. The only way to fix this is to regenerate the CSR and obtain new SSL certificate (your SSL provider may or may not charge you extra fee for replacing certificate).

Comment: Please stop confusing yourself and others by misusing the SSL term when talking about X.509 certificates. There exist no SSL providers, and no SSL certificates.

Comment: I am not confused, but sounds like you are. Just google `SSL certificate` or `SSL Provider` - you'll be suprised how common those terms are.

Comment: It's worth looking at profile sometimes. Google is full of BS, and common terms are not more correct than your misuse of the term.

Comment: Which profile are you talking about? Also, I don't see a point in debating whether some term is "correct" or not, you're obviously entitled to your own opinion.

Comment: User profile. Insisting on your ignorance is not the best idea - your answer has been referenced to by another user which means that people actually see your mistake.

Comment: There is no mistake. Insisting that `SSL certificate` is a BS term when the term is widely used by all major players in the market (verisign, thawte, digcert and tons of others) only hurts your self-proclaimed "guru" status. And, yes - people will see that.

Answer (score 1):

If the certificate is from Go Daddy as well, then there is no cost to re-key the certificate.

To Re-key an SSL Certificate

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click SSL Certificates.
3. Next to the certificate you want to re-key, click Launch.
4. In the Filters list, click Certificates.
5. Click the common name for the certificate you want to re-key.
6. Click Re-Key.
7. There might be a step here, depending on hosted here/elsewhere.
8. In CSR, paste your CSR text.
9. Select a certificate issuing organization, and then click Re-Key.
10. Select a Server type, and then click Download.